# css arrows not coming correctly in IE 8

Tags: html, css, navigation, doctype

I am using html and css provided in the following **[a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBB3B/4/).**

It is working fine in other browsers but the arrows are not appearing correctly in IE 8.0.
[image: Below is what I see in IE 8.0]

This happens due **missing DOCTYPE declaration** not present in the HTML document. Unfortunately,I cannot add DOCTYPE declaration as it causes a lot of thing in the existing app break. I just wanted to know if it is possible to fix this problem without adding DOCTYPE declaration.

Please help!

**EDIT:**
I found following css code to make after triangle work in quirk mode (sort of)

```
.wizard-steps .a-after{
BORDER-BOTTOM: transparent 12px dashed;
BORDER-LEFT: transparent 12px dashed;
BORDER-TOP: transparent 12px dashed; 
BORDER-RIGHT: transparent 12px dashed;
line-height: 0;
POSITION: relative; 
WIDTH: 0px; 
DISPLAY: inline-block; 
HEIGHT: 0px; 
VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; 
}
```

Updated the **[a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBB3B/6/)** with that. I am not able to make the before triangle work also it remove the after triangle from normal steps.

I am not very proficient with CSS can anybody please help !!!

Comment: it works just fine for me in ie8...

Comment: JS Fiddle displays fine but if you take the html and css code and run it locally in IE 8.0 it gives that problem

Comment: what problam does adding a doctype make? it is an important part of the code..

Comment: The existing application works fine without DOCTYPE and adding doctype causes several of the UI elements to break..

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : **no**.

You pointed the error yourself : *This happens due missing DOCTYPE declaration not present in the HTML document.*

With no indication about the doctype, IE goes in quirks mode (think ie6) by default. There are some extra step you can take to **not go** in quirks mode.

[Here's a chart about how IE determine which mode to display](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx) and [this page provide info about defining a document compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx).

And then... the rest of your page will then break since it **needs** quirks mode. The solution is to redo this code to be *quirks mode compatible*. (*"I cannot add DOCTYPE declaration as it causes a lot of thing in the existing app break"*) That or... redo the whole app!

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already found the answer, the missing doctype, I would just like to point out that you will find other browser issues without doctype declared. It's needed for a reason. This is just the first issue you've found, I would expect more if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Following CSS worked (even in quirk mode) and gave me close enough result to achieve what I was trying.

```
/*navigation css*/
.wizard-steps{ position:relative;clear:both;font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica,   Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:700;margin:20px 10px 0;padding:0}
.wizard-steps .step{position:relative}
.wizard-steps div{float:left;}
.wizard-steps span{display:block;float:left;font-size:10px;text-align:center;width:15px;line-height:15px;color:#ccc;background:#FFF;border:2px solid #CCC;-webkit-border-radius:10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;border-radius:10px;margin:2px 5px 0 0}
.wizard-steps label{position:relative;display:block;height:24px;float:left;font-size:11px;line-height:24px;color:#666;background:#ECECEC;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);padding:0 10px 0 3px}
.wizard-steps .a-before{width:0px;height:0px;border-top:12px solid #ECECEC;border-bottom:12px solid #ECECEC;border-left:12px solid transparent;line-height: 0;POSITION: relative;}
.wizard-steps .a-after{BORDER-BOTTOM: transparent 12px dashed;BORDER-LEFT: transparent 12px dashed;BORDER-TOP: transparent 12px dashed;BORDER-RIGHT: transparent 12px dashed;line-height: 0;POSITION: relative;WIDTH: 0px;DISPLAY: inline-block;HEIGHT: 0px;VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle;}
.wizard-steps .step .a-after{border-left:12px solid #ECECEC}
.wizard-steps .completed-step label{color:#163038;background:#7EBFE6}
.wizard-steps .completed-step .a-before{border-top:12px solid #7EBFE6;border-bottom:12px solid #7EBFE6}
.wizard-steps .completed-step .a-after{border-left:12px solid #7EBFE6}
.wizard-steps .completed-step span{border:2px solid #7EBFE6;color:#163038;text-shadow:none}
.wizard-steps .active-step label{color:#FFF;background:#019BDB;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8)}
.wizard-steps .active-step .a-before{border-top:12px solid #019BDB;border-bottom:12px solid #019BDB}
.wizard-steps .active-step .a-after{border-left:12px solid #019BDB}
.wizard-steps .active-step span{color:#293E68;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);-moz-box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);text-shadow:none;border:2px solid #A3C1C9}
.wizard-steps .completed-step:hover label,.wizard-steps .active-step:hover label{color:#fff;background:#8F061E;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8)}
.wizard-steps .completed-step:hover span,.wizard-steps .active-step:hover span{color:#8F061E}
.wizard-steps .completed-step:hover .a-before,.wizard-steps .active-step:hover .a-before{border-top:12px solid #8F061E;border-bottom:12px solid #8F061E}
.wizard-steps .completed-step:hover .a-after,.wizard-steps .active-step:hover .a-after{border-left:12px solid #8F061E}
```

Also updated the **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBB3B/7/)**